# Circular trajectory for sprite in LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx, sprites

I want four sprites to orbit a single origin point. But if I use like this

```
    sprite_p1_avatar = new Sprite(dummyText);
    sprite_p1_avatar.setPosition(200, 200);
    sprite_p1_avatar.setOrigin(100, 100);

    sprite_p2_avatar = new Sprite(dummyText);
    sprite_p2_avatar.setPosition(300, 300);
    sprite_p2_avatar.setOrigin(100, 100);

    sprite_p3_avatar = new Sprite(dummyText);
    sprite_p3_avatar.setPosition(400, 400);
    sprite_p3_avatar.setOrigin(100, 100);

    sprite_p4_avatar = new Sprite(dummyText);
    sprite_p4_avatar.setPosition(500, 500);
    sprite_p4_avatar.setOrigin(100, 100);

    sprite_p1_avatar.rotate(40 * delta);

    sprite_p1_avatar.draw(batch);

    sprite_p2_avatar.rotate(40 * delta);
    sprite_p2_avatar.draw(batch);

    sprite_p3_avatar.rotate(40 * delta);
    sprite_p3_avatar.draw(batch);

    sprite_p4_avatar.rotate(40 * delta);
    sprite_p4_avatar.draw(batch);
```

the sprite get inverted while revolving, as these sprites are profile pictures of users I want them to stay straight while orbiting at every point. Is there any way to move the sprites along a circular path without rotating.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather simple approach. To keep it pointing up, it'd be easier to translate sprites on your own.

- Calculate current angle of your rotation each frame
- Then calculate offset from origin (See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)) for maths)
- Add offset to origin and set your position

  ```
  public static Vector2 getCurrentPosition(float degrees, Vector2 origin, float radius) {
      //pre-calculate sin and cos
      float radians = degrees * MathUtils.degreesToRadians;
      float sin = MathUtils.sin(radians);
      float cos = MathUtils.cos(radians);

      float offsetX = cos * radius;
      float offsetY = sin * radius;

      float currentX = origin.x + offsetX;
      float currentY = origin.y + offsetY;

      //return your position or set it here, nevermind,  whatever suits you
  }
  ```